# Sorting Values in Crosstab on IBM Cognos Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, cognos

How to Sort my values/measure descending on my crosstab. i'm using IBM Cognos Analytics Dashboard by the way.

Comment: What does websphere have to do with using a Cognos dashboard?  Are you thinking the answer will involve hacking text files or recompiling Java programs deep inside the Cognos install?

Comment: what version of Cognos i.e. 11.1.7?